# s3 bucket policy to add exception

Tags: amazon-s3, policy, bucket

Hi I am trying to write the permissions policy to access my bucket.

I want to deny access to a particular user-agent and allow access to all other user agents. With the below policy the access is getting denied to all.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1456658595000",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "NSPlayer"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know how should I write such policy so that except one user agent all others are able to access the same.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be written this way!

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "SID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "NSPlayer"
                }
            },
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This solution works if bucket objects are not public read/write. One related answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739337/deny-access-to-user-agent-to-access-a-bucket-in-aws-s3):   [Deny access to user agent to access a bucket in AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739337/deny-access-to-user-agent-to-access-a-bucket-in-aws-s3)

Comment: Be careful -- you are granting COMPLETE control of your Amazon S3 buckets to everybody (as long as they don't use NSPlayer). This means they can upload, download and delete your data. It is safer to only grant access to API calls and buckets necessary for your users -- and no more. One way would be to grant access to S3 via normal policies, then use your above policy with a "Like" and "DENY" to specifically deny NSPlayer access.

Comment: you comment is useful.. Could you please edit the answer properly so that others also have understanding when they see the answer!

Comment: How do we give permissions only to api calls only. Could you please another answer properly that will help me

Comment: Manish -- AWS only works via API calls. Even the Management Console makes API calls that require IAM permissions. What were you wanting to 'not' give permissions to?

Comment: To user agent nsplayer