# Amazon S3 Bucket Policy Block User Agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to block a specific user agent from amazon s3. I'm fairly new to S3 and typically do this in the .htaccess file which I understand isn't possible with amazon.

I saw this [Deny access to user agent to access a bucket in AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739337/deny-access-to-user-agent-to-access-a-bucket-in-aws-s3). The solution seems to look something like this:

```
{ "Version": "2012-10-17", 
  "Statement": [{ 
              "Effect": "Deny", 
              "Principal": "*", 
              "Action": "s3:*",

              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*", 
              "Condition": 
                      { "StringLike": { "aws:UserAgent": "*NSPlayer*" } } 
}] 
}
```

But, I would still like to allow access to the site to all other users except that user agent. My policy currently looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.examplesite.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get invalid json when I try to implement it. So, I am just curious what is the correct way to format this? I would like to have public access but be able to block a few different user agents. Also, would the user agents be comma separated if I want to block multiple?

Thanks for the help it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.examplesite.com/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyUserAgents",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.examplesite.com/*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:UserAgent": ["*Firefox*", ... more UserAgents ...]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```